# A dumb question from M-L inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to ask a dumb question from M-L inequality which reads as:

Let $f$ be continuous on a contour $C$ of length $L.$ Then $$\left|\int_C f(z)dz\right|
\le\int_C|f(z)||dz|\le M\int_C|dz|= ML$$

Now my questions are *what is the meaning of $|dz|$* and *how to interpret the integral $\int_C|f(z)||dz|$ while performing the calculation?*

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $z(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$ for $t\in[0,1]$ parametrizes $C$.  Then

$$\int_Cdz = \int_0^1 \dot{z}(t) dt=z(1)-z(0)\quad\mathrm{and}\quad\int_C|dz| = \int_0^1 |\dot{z}(t)|dt=\int_0^1\sqrt{\dot{x}^2(t)+\dot{y}^2(t)}dt.$$

The first integral will evaluate to a complex number that is the difference of the endpoints of $C$ viewed as a curve in $\mathbb{C}$ and he second to a real value that is the arclength of $C$ viewed as a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$; this should illustrate the difference between $dz$ and $|dz|$.